# How to disable clicked button in a map in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, button, disable, array-map

When i try to click on a button all the buttons get disabled

Any help will be appertiated

Comment: I am collecting response from backend and applying map on it and added button to every response.Basically i am having add to cart button

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a loading condition

````
<Table.Cell>
  <Button onClick={() => {
    if(loader == false){
      alert("test")
    }
  }} outline={true} gradientDuoTone="cyanToBlue">
    Edit
  </Button>
</Table.Cell>```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const MapExample = () => {
  const [disabledButtons, setDisabledButtons] = useState([]);

  const handleButtonClick = (buttonId) => {
    // Disable the clicked button
    setDisabledButtons((prevDisabledButtons) => [prevDisabledButtons, buttonId]);
  };

  const renderButtons = () => {
    const buttonData = [
      { id: 1, label: 'Button 1' },
      { id: 2, label: 'Button 2' },
      { id: 3, label: 'Button 3' },
      // Add more buttons as needed
    ];

    return buttonData.map((button) => (
      <button
        key={button.id}
        onClick={() => handleButtonClick(button.id)}
        disabled={disabledButtons.includes(button.id)}
      >
        {button.label}
      </button>
    ));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Click the buttons</h2>
      {renderButtons()}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MapExample;
```

In this example shows how to create buttons that can be disabled after clicking. It uses state `disabledButtons` to keep track of clicked buttons and dynamically disables them in the user interface. The `handleButtonClick` function updates the state when a button is clicked, and the `renderButtons` function generates buttons with appropriate `disabled` states.